# Mercurial list all csets which are result of merge

Tags: mercurial

Is it possible to list all commited changesets that are result of let's say branch "A" merged into "default"

```
   /o-o\"B"
o-o-----O-o-o-O-o-o-o "default"
 \-o-o-o-o---/"A"
```

This is a crude example which shows merge commits as capital "O" so what would like to know if I can only list all those capital "O" changesets.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`hg log -r "merge()"` should do what you want.  See [`hg help revsets`](http://www.selenic.com/hg/help/revsets) for more details.